# A question about "Ignoring visible gpu device and Adding visible gpu device"

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am running tf in two ways.

First, I use python3.5 with tf 1.12.0, when I run `tf.Session()`, then python3.5 output is like:

```
2020-07-16 16:40:36.993973: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-07-16 16:40:37.191067: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:07:00.0
totalMemory: 11.92GiB freeMemory: 11.85GiB
2020-07-16 16:40:37.191124: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-07-16 16:40:37.606605: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-07-16 16:40:37.606665: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2020-07-16 16:40:37.606676: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2020-07-16 16:40:37.607545: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 11489 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
*********************************************************************************************************
```

Then, I use C_API with tf 1.12.0,and `libtensorflow.so` and libtensorflow_frame.so`as copy form python3.5 packages. When I run`TF_SessionRun()`, output is:

```
TF VERSION:1.12.0
2020-07-16 15:49:22.423989: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2020-07-16 15:49:22.631974: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:07:00.0
totalMemory: 11.92GiB freeMemory: 11.85GiB
2020-07-16 15:49:22.632046: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1482] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0, compute capability: 3.7) with Cuda compute capability 3.7. The minimum required Cuda capability is 6.0.
2020-07-16 15:49:22.632067: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-07-16 15:49:22.632082: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2020-07-16 15:49:22.632095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N
```

Why python3.5 with tf-gpu 1.12.0 can use k80 gpu ,but c_api with tf-gpu 1.12.0 cannot be used with k80?

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the error message that you need a GPU with compute capability of `6.0`. The compute capability of your GPU is `3.7`.

`Ignoring visible GPU device (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0, compute capability: 3.7) with Cuda compute capability 3.7. The minimum required Cuda capability is 6.0.`

As a solution in this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25329), one person recommended to downgrade to `1.11.0`, that fixed his issue.

Comment: Sorry, my question is : why tf1.12.0 with python3.5 can find k80 gpu and can use it to run ,but c_api with tf1.12.0 give me a warning , c_api can find k80 but k80 compute capability is lower than tf1.12.0 require.